# Java - Reflection how to find the type is enum

Tags: java, reflection, types, enums

i try to find at run time the fully qualified type of the field type using reflection like the following.

```
if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(Integer.class)){
                            f.set(clsObject, DefaultParamValuesEnum.INTEGER.getDefaultInt());

                    }
```

when i try like the following for enum it gives exception :

```
else if(! Modifier.isFinal(f.getModifiers()) && type.equals(enum.class)){
                            f.set(clsObject,DefaultParamValuesEnum.LONGVALUE.getDefaultLong());  
                        }
```

following error i get:

```
Syntax error on token "enum", invalid
```

How to figure out the enum type?

would some one help me on this please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To check if a class is of enum type, simply use [`Class.isEnum()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isEnum%28%29)